# SImplify code to group in r

Tags: r, simplify

I have a data frame like this:

```
ID PA   WA  PC
1   2   -6   8 
2   2   -2   7
3   3    7   2
4  -3    3  -6
5   3   20  12
6  15  -17  18
7   3    6  10
```

I tried to group IDs based on their scores in PA, WA and PC.

I already used this, but it is so cumbersome:

```
NEW1 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA< -5 & WA < -5 & PC> 5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW2 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA >5 & WA < -5 & PC< -5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW3 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA < -5 & WA >5 & PC< -5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW4 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA < -5 & WA < -5 & PC< -5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW5 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA > 5 & WA >5 & PC< -5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW6 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA >5 & WA < -5 & PC>5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW7 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA < -5 & WA >5 & PC>5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW8 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA >5 & WA >5 & PC>5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW9 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA<5 & PA>-5 & WA<5 & WA>-5 & PC<5 & PC>-5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW10 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA < -5 & WA < -5 & PC<5 & PC>-5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW11 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA<5 & PA>-5 & WA < -5 & PC<5 & PC>-5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW12 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA<5 & PA>-5 & WA<5 & WA>-5 & PC< -5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW13 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA< -5 & WA<5 & WA>-5 & PC<5 & PC>-5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW14 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA < -5 & WA<5 & WA>-5 & PC< -5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW15 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA< -5 & WA<5 & WA>-5 & PC>5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW16 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA < -5 & WA >5 & PC<5 & PC>-5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW17 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA<5 & PA>-5 & WA < -5 & PC>5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW18 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA<5 & PA>-5 & WA<5 & WA>-5 & PC< -5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW19 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA<5 & PA>-5 & WA<5 & WA>-5 & PC>5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW20 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA<5 & PA>-5 & WA >5 & PC< -5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW21 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA<5 & PA>-5 & WA >5 & PC<5 & PC>-5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW22 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA<5 & PA>-5 & WA >5 & PC>5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW23 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA >5 & WA < -5 & PC<5 & PC>-5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW24 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA >5 & WA<5 & WA>-5 & PC< -5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW25 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA >5 & WA<5 & WA>-5 & PC<5 & PC>-5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW26 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA >5 & WA<5 & WA>-5 & PC>5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
NEW27 <- subset(WA.PC.PA, PA >5 & WA >5 & PC<5 & PC>-5, select=c(id, PA, WA, PC))
```

As you can see, I group each score into three levels, <-5, between -5~5 and >5. But I want to 1) simplify the code as I need to rewrite the whole thing when I want to assign different number to cutscores of each test.

How can I do that?

Comment: There's a `findInterval` function. After using that to define categorical variables for each variable, you could just tag the observations with their group labels. That would be best for ensuring that your subsets are exhaustive and distinct (cover everything in the original set with no overlap). In a data.table, you can tag groups with  `DT[,groupname:=.GRP,by=list(PAcode,WAcode,PCcode)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use cut followed by interaction then split. Basically, cut will define the partitions of each variable, e.g.,

```
paCuts = with(WA.PC.PA, cut(PA, c(-Inf, -5, 5, Inf)))
waCuts = with(WA.PC.PA, cut(PA, c(-Inf, -5, 5, Inf)))
levels = interaction(paCuts, waCuts)
split(WA.PC.PA, levels)
```

The benefit here is that you think about your partitioning as data, i.e., in a vector, versus code; in a conditional statement. It makes changing the various cuts a breeze.

Comment: Thanks! @jimmyb, this works awesome. But how can I export the ids, since split(WA.PC.PA, levels) produces a list.

Comment: You can split anything, including the IDS, for instance, split(WA.PC.PA$IDS, levels)